# Using CiviEvent Shopping Cart with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Is it possible to navigate to the View Cart page in Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

It's Ok, it's early. I worked it out.

http://locahost:8080/**civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/view_cart**